# Onmousedown event function handling not able to grab the value of an outer variable

Tags: javascript, event-handling

In my `cell.onmousedown` function when I `console.log(cell)` it returns the value of cell defined in the outer function however when I try to `console.log(something else)` like `selectedText` it returns that `selectedText` is `undefined` even though I already defined in the outer function which has worked for me before when coding something similar. Can anyone see what is the issue here?

Here is my function for creating a grid and handling events when a div in the grid is pressed:

```js
function createGrid(rows, cols) {
    let mousePressed = false;
    let wordsFound = 0;
    let selectedText = '';
    let selectedCells = [];
    let variables = [];
    grid.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
    grid.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < cols; column++) {
            let cell = document.createElement('div');
            cell.innerText = randomChoice(alphabet);
            cell.id = `${column} ${row}`;
            cell.onmousedown = function() {
                console.log(cell)
                console.log(selectedText)
                variables = mouseDown(cell, selectedText, selectedCells);
                selectedText = variables[0];
                selectedCells = variables[1];
                mousePressed = variables[2];
            }
            cell.onmouseover = function() {
                variables = mouseOver();
                selectedText = variables[0];
                selectedCells = variables[1];
            }
            cell.onmouseup = function() {
                variables = mouseUp(cell, selectedText, selectedCells);
                selectedText = variables[0];
                selectedCells = variables[1];
                mousePressed = variables[2];
            }
            grid.appendChild(cell).className = 'grid-item';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the issue. The `onmouseover` was being run when I didn't realize and ran a function with no parameters when they were expected. So then when `selectectedText` and `selectedCells` were changed to the value according to the function their value was changed to undefined making it look like the variables were never defined in the first place.

Changes made:

```
cell.onmouseover = function() {
                variables = mouseOver(cell, selectedText, selectedCells, mousePressed);
                selectedText = variables[0];
                selectedCells = variables[1];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `var` instead of `let` in the createGrid function.

> `let` is a block scope declaration for variables.

```
function letTest() {
 let x = 1;
  {
    let x = 2;  // different variable
    console.log(x);  // 2
  }
  console.log(x);  // 1
}
```